# The way to pass multi-values to JQuery from PHP via JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

In `PHP server side` I have these values which want to pass back to `JQuery` to update client side infomation.

E.g:

```
fileSN  fileTotalNumber fileTotalSize
1       3               455
2       4               555
3       1               755
4       1               155
```

The PHP code to get each data:

```
$fileData = array();

while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array( $load_files_data_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 

        $fileSN  = $row['file_sn'];
        $fileTotalNumber = $row['fileTotalNumber '];
        $fileTotalSize= $row['fileTotalNumber '];

        // only one data here , and need more data associated with fileSN
        $fileData[$fileSN] = $fileTotalNumber;  

    }

return json_encode($fileIds);
```

And at the client side,my HTML code :

```
<ul>
  <li fileSN='1' fileTotalNumber='3' fileTotalSize='345'>update li information</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

My JQuery code :

```
$.ajax({  
  ...
  success: function(result){                  
    result = jQuery.parseJSON( result );

    $.each(result, function(index, value) {

         //  need more values to update other attributes

         $('#'+obj.FMMWID+'UL li[fileSN='+index+']')
         .addClass('igtomdSelectedItem')
         .attr('allfiles',value);  
         //console.log(value)
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: you'll have to `echo json_encode($data)` on server side and on client side do a `$.aja`x call w/ data type JSON enabled.

Comment: Yes.I have done that.And I need a data structure to wrap all data I want and pass them back to JQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an associative array of your table information like:

```
$tableData[$rownumber]['field1'] = 'fieldvalue';
$tableData[$rownumber]['field2'] = '2ndFieldValue';
```

And do that for all your rows and fields, you can then encode that array using json_encode().

So if you return your data to jQuery as `data`  you can then access stuff like:

```
data[0].field1
```

Where 0 is a valid row number and field1 is one of the array fields.